# Winsock Kernel - Reusing socket return error 0xc0000184

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, winsock, wdf

I am developing WDF driver that uses Winsock Kernel module connecting network. I have encounter problem when I try to reuse socket. I am successfully creating, binding and connecting socket. After that I am disconnecting socket with WskDisconnect function with success status. However when I try to reconnect using same socket I get error 0xc0000184. Any ideas why I can't reuse my socket? Binding fails as well.

Comment: Reconnecting, once used socket, even to different port still results in fault so it's not related to remote port.

Comment: Anyone familiar with windows kernel?